# is there a way to order an Arabic text in reportlab python pdf generator

Tags: python, django, reportlab

i'm creating an Arabic pdf using python report lab , the problem is the Arabic text is being displayed from the end to the beginning, it means that once the first line has finished its width it's appending the next line above it , note that every line is ordered correctly but the order of the lines as a group is reversed

```
def arabic_text(doc, styles):
    arabic_text_style = get_arabic_text_style(styles)
    arabic_title_style = ParagraphStyle(name='Heading1',borderPadding=3,fontName="Arabic", alignment=2, fontSize=18, leading=16)
    storys = []
    paragraphs = paragraph.objects.all()
    for para in paragraphs:
        title = Paragraph(get_display(arabic_reshaper.reshape(para.title)), arabic_title_style)
        text = Paragraph(get_display(arabic_reshaper.reshape(para.text)), arabic_text_style)
        paragraph_content = KeepTogether([title, Spacer(1, 30), text])
        storys.append(paragraph_content)
        storys.append(Spacer(1, 60))
    return storys
```